# preg_match_all Output with Multiple Possibilities

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am searching a line using preg_match_all, but it is not known exactly what this line will look like. For example, it could look like this:

```
XXX012-013-015-######
```

Or it could look like this:

```
XXX012-013-015-XXX001-002-######
```

Where the 'X's are any letter and the '#'s are any number.

This is the relevant portion of the preg_match_all code that works exactly as expected if the line was always setup like the first example:

```
if (preg_match_all('([A-Z]{3})((?:[0-9]{3}[->]{1}){1,32})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})...rest of code...#', $wwalist, $matches)) {

$wwaInfo['locationabbrev'][$wwanum] = $matches[2][$keys[$wwanum]];

}
```

The `$matches[2]` will display "012-013-015" as expected. Since the first part, xxx012-013-015, can repeat, I need for the preg_match_all $matches[2] to display the following if it is run on the second example:

012-013-015-001-002

This was my attempt, but it does not work:

```
if (preg_match_all('#([A-Z]{3})((?:[0-9]{3}[->]{1}){1,32})((?:[A-Z]{3}){0,1})(?:((?:[0-9]{3}[->]{1}){1,3}){0,3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})...rest of code...#', $wwalist, $matches)) {
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: For the second example you wrote "-XXX001" but want it to return "-001", so you want to also strip any present non-numeric characters?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I don't think that RegEx can do that directly for you. You could try to match the entire string and filter it with PHP code afterwards (ie. removing non-numerical characters).

Comment: Any idea how to match the string when it could be either of the possibilities shown?

Comment: Basically `[A-Z]{3}(([0-9]{3}-){3}([A-Z]{3}([0-9]{3}-){2})?)[0-9]{6}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to match and join matches in the same step.

Will this work for you:

Code: ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u9dDZ9/2)) ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33d33853a2290691f267c686aadf05957fd33163))

```
$strings=[
    'ABC012-013-015-XYZ001-002-345435',
    'ABC012-013-015-345453',
    'XYZ013-014-015-016-EFG017-123456'
];

foreach($strings as $s){
    if(preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}\d{3}/',$s)){  // check if string qualifies
        echo 'Match found.  Prepared string: ';
        $s=preg_replace('/([A-Z]{3}|-\d{6})/','',$s);  // remove unwanted substrings
        echo "$s\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Match found.  Prepared string: 012-013-015-001-002
Match found.  Prepared string: 012-013-015
Match found.  Prepared string: 013-014-015-016-017
```

Comment: @hunter21188 If my simple patterns don't work for all of your cases, or this is just not what you are trying to achieve, please leave me a comment explaining what isn't right and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The main problem I see with that is the strings are never constant. I have no way of knowing what they will be.

Comment: @hunter21188 Well, regex patterns literally need to be based on patterns in your text.  If you cannot isolate a pattern, your regex methods will never be trustworthy.  If you can provide any additional details or differing sample data, we may be able to help you.  How do you _know_ which substrings _you_ want to extract (in human terms)?

Comment: Right. The pattern is known. There are two options (both of which you show in your strings), but the sets of 3 numbers can repeat up to 32 times, which I account for in my original regex code. The output I need is exactly what you show in your code. But you are using a defined set of strings. So I'm not sure how I would use that exactly.

Comment: @hunter21188 Okay, can you show me some more samples (including the really long ones) in a regex101 link?

Comment: I don't actually need to include the preg_match check do I?  You just want to replaced result string, right?

Comment: @hunter21188 1:30am here, I'll check back on this question in the morning to see if you have provided anything new for me to play with.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for helping out. The main issue I am having is that there are two separate preg_match possibilities. One that accounts for this pattern `OHZ012-014-015-060815-` (repeating the sets of 3 numbers up to 32 times, and one that accounts for this pattern, `OHZ012-014-015-PAZ001-060815-`, repeating all sets of 3 numbers up to 32 possible times. I need something that says if the first pattern is true, do this, AND if the 2nd pattern is true, do this. Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/3FQ0JB/3

Comment: @hunter21188 Now we are making progress.  I didn't know what the rest of the full string looked like.  Can you provide 3 or 4 more full string samples?  If I can find consistencies between your input strings and your desired results, I can make an accurate pattern for you.  From your sample I am beginning to think that the `hyphen followed by the six-digit number` represents the beginning of the text that you don't want to match.  Please show me a few more examples.

Comment: Are you only doing one string at a time? or might you be searching a larger text for multiple qualifying strings?  In the following demo, I am doing multiple searches (3) on a single body of text.  https://regex101.com/r/3FQ0JB/6  Knowing the full text that is being searched lets me know if I _should_ be using the `^` to mark the "start of the line".  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You are exactly right. I am searching a webpage that may contain just one qualifying string or a number of qualifying strings. The examples you show in your demo are all the possible ways a string could be formatted. I do want to strip all the letters prior to the -###### (hypen 6-digit number). I assume I can set `$strings` (as per your initial answer) to equal the URL. But then I'm not sure what the foreach loop would look like. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: There was one other possibility, it can be a `-` or a `>` in between the sets of 3 numbers. I have updated your initial expression to account for this. Is the lookahead necessary? Just asking because I removed it and it still works as expected. With this example (https://regex101.com/r/3FQ0JB/8), it now works exactly how I need! The last step is to remove the three letters from the sets of 3 numbers in the first part.

Comment: Ok, so I used `$matches[2] = preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', ' ', $matches[2]);` and that made everything work as I wanted. Thanks so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a replace call and then output a new string with the matches, so for example:

```
ABC012-013-015-XYZ001-002-345435
ABC012-013-015-345453
XYZ013-014-015-016-EFG017-123456

$rep = preg_replace( '/(?mi-Us)([^0-9-\n]{3,})|-[0-9]{4,}/', '', $str) ;
echo ( $rep );
```

**Should result in:**

```
012-013-015-001-002
012-013-015
013-014-015-016-017
```

**To output to an array:**

```
$mat = preg_match_all( '/([0-9-]+)\n/', $rep, $res) ;
print_r( $res[1] ) ;

foreach( $res[1] as $result ) {
    echo $result . "\n" ;
}
```

*For the code you've shown you could probably do:*

```
$rep = preg_replace( '/(?mi-Us)([^0-9-\n]{3,})|-[0-9]{4,}/', '', $wwalist ) ;

if (preg_match_all('/([0-9-]+)\n/', $rep, $matches)) {

    $wwaInfo['locationabbrev'][$wwanum] = $matches[1][$keys[$wwanum]];
    print_r( $wwaInfo['locationabbrev'][$wwanum] ); // comment out when done testing
}
```

*Which should return the array:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => 012-013-015-001-002
    [1] => 012-013-015
    [2] => 013-014-015-016-017
)
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out how I would implement this. Would I put the code within my initial If statement or outside of it? I have tried a few different ways, but to no avail. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @hunter21188: See my edit; you might have to change it a bit since I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but you should get the general idea of how to include it.